# Manufacturing watch progress

Tags: eve-online

I am doing tutorial quests in Industry. I set up a manufacturing job at the science & industry.

The items and blueprints are gone from the hangar and nothing has returned back yet. I am guessing it is still in progress. I am not even sure it is, cause I searched the whole UI and nothing indicates that I am currently building something, except when I try to build something else I get the message "Your skill only allows you to build 1 at a time"

Anyways where can I see its progress? I want to know how much time left and some proof that I am actually doing the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the left side you have a button with a blue-ish image and the hover text: Science and Industry

There you have a menu with several tabs, one of which is inspecting the status of your jobs. If you finished a job it might be necessary to manually retrieve it once it is finished. Otherwise you might not be able to start a new one.